# Iterative methods: What happens when the spectral radius of a matrix is exactly 1?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I know that an iterative method (I'm using Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel in this case) will converge **iff** the spectral radius (max absolute value of eigenvalues) of its iterative matrix is strictly less than 1.

I've encountered a situation where the spectral radius of the iterative matrix is **exactly** 1. I'm pretty sure that it will converge for certain initial "guesses", but not others. Why is this the case? Is there a way to determine which initial guesses result in convergence?

Comment: Look at the diagonalization of the iteration matrix. Some of the components of a generic vector will fail to decay (those in the direction of the large eigenvalues).

Comment: @lan Hi. This is my question too. Could you please give more details or introduce some reference to read more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $A=M-N,$ where in Gauss-Seidel method $M=D-L,$ and $N=U,$ then the iteration matrix $B_{G}=$
$M^{-1} N=(D-L)^{-1} U .$ For the Gauss-Seidel method to converge, the spectral radius of $B_{G}$ should be less than $1,$ i.e.
$$
\rho\left(B_{G}\right)=\max _{\lambda \in \Lambda\left(B_{G}\right)}|\lambda|<1
$$
Let $(\lambda, v)$ be a pair of eigenvalue and eigenvector of $B_{G},\left(\lambda \in \Lambda\left(B_{G}\right)\right)$ then
$$
\begin{aligned}
B_{G} v &=(D-L)^{-1} U v=\lambda v \\
U v &=\lambda(D-L) v \\
-\sum_{j>i} A(i, j) * v(j) &=\lambda \sum_{j \leqslant i} A(i, j) * v(j)=\lambda A(i, i) * v(i)+\lambda \sum_{j<i} A(i, j) * v(j) \quad \text { for } i=1,2, \cdots, n \\
\Longrightarrow \lambda A(i, i) * v(i) &=-\sum_{j>i} A(i, j) * v(j)-\lambda \sum_{j<i} A(i, j) * v(j) \quad \text { for } i=1,2, \cdots, n \\
\Longrightarrow|\lambda||A(i, i)||v(i)| &=\left|-\sum_{j>i} A(i, j) * v(j)-\lambda \sum_{j<i} A(i, j) * v(j)\right| \quad \text { for } i=1,2, \cdots, n \\
& \leqslant \sum_{j>i}|A(i, j)||v(j)|+|\lambda| \sum_{j<i}|A(i, j)||v(j)| \\
& \leqslant \max \{1,|\lambda|\}\left(\sum_{j>i}|A(i, j)||v(j)|+\sum_{j<i}|A(i, j)||v(j)|\right) \quad\\
&=\max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}|A(i, j)||v(j)|
\end{aligned}
$$
But $v(j) \leqslant\|v\|_{\infty},$ thus
$$
|\lambda||v(i)|\leqslant \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}\left|\frac{A(i, j)}{A(i, i)} \right| \|v_{\infty}\|=\|v\|_{\infty} \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}\left|\frac{A(i, j)}{A(i, i)}\right| \quad \text { for } i=1,2, \cdots, n
$$
Let $i_{0}$ be such that $\left|v\left(i_{0}\right)\right|=\|v\|_{\infty},$ then we have that
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\lambda|\left|v\left(i_{0}\right)\right| \leqslant &\|v\|_{\infty} \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i_{0}}^{n}\left|\frac{A\left(i_{0}, j\right)}{A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)}\right| \\
\therefore & |\lambda|  \leqslant \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i_{0}}^{n}\left|\frac{A\left(i_{0}, j\right)}{A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)}\right|
\;\llap{\mathrel{\boxed{\phantom{\therefore  |\lambda|  \leqslant \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i_{0}}^{n}\left|\frac{A\left(i_{0}, j\right)}{A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)}\right|}}}}
\end{aligned}
$$
Considering $A$ to be strictly diagonally dominant, that is to say :
$$
|A(i, i)|>\sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i}^{n}|A(i, j)|, \quad \forall i=1,2, \cdots, n
$$
We will have that :
$$
\begin{aligned}
|\lambda|& \leqslant \max \{1,|\lambda|\} \sum_{j=1 \atop j \neq i_{0}}^{n}\left|\frac{A\left(i_{0}, j\right)}{A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)}\right| \\
&<\max \{1,|\lambda|\} \frac{1}{\left|A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)\right|}\left|A\left(i_{0}, i_{0}\right)\right|=\max \{1,|\lambda|\}
\end{aligned}
\tag{1}
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\text { If }|\lambda| \color{red}{\geqslant} 1, \text { then this leads to a contradiction since equation (1) becomes }|\lambda|\color{red}{<}|\lambda| \text { . }\\
&\text { Thus, }|\lambda|<1 \text { and } :
\end{aligned}
$$
\boxed{\rho\left(B_{G}\right)=\max _{\lambda \in \Lambda\left(B_{G}\right)}|\lambda|<1}
$$