# Iteration matrix and convergence

Tags: matrices, partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Assuming $G_{JA}$ is an iteration matrix for Jacobi Algorithm:

$G_{JA}(A) = I -D^{-1}A$

$D$ is the diagonal of $A$.

The sufficient condition for convergence is spectral radius less than one($\rho(G) <1$). Now, what happen if the spectral radius is equal to 1? Is there a way to set the parameter(such as initial guess) that guarantee convergence  in this case?

I would appreciate any guidance on this matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about the one dimensional case first. (Also, your question is lacking detail, so I'm just guessing you have an iteration of the form $x_{n+1} = G x_n$.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added more details.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out your point. For one dimension, the eigenvalue of G should be either 1 or  -1 . But it is not possible for one dimension since $D^{-1}$=1/a and $G_{JA}(A)=0$. I don't quite get it.

Comment: If the spectral radius of $G$ is $1$, then in the one dimensional case you have $G= \pm 1$. If $G= -1$ it can never converge.

Comment: For one dimension G is always $0$. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Oops, yes, I made that suggestion before the elaboration.

Answer (score 3):

$\rho(G_{JA}) < 1$ is a necessary (and sufficient) condition for the convergence.

With your notation for the iteration matrix (G), we can write a stationary, first order, linear iterative method as:
$$
\mathbf{x}^{k+1} = G \mathbf{x}^k + \mathbf{f}
$$

For an iterative method, (as Jacobi is) the theorem is:

> **Theorem**
>   An iterative method is convergent $\iff$  the spectral radius of the iterative matrix $\rho(G) < 1$

I will prove only the forward implication.

Suppose for contradiction that $\rho(G) \geq 1$, i.e. $\exists$ an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of G with $|\lambda| \geq 1$; let $\mathbf{v}$ be the corresponding 
eigenvector. We choose as starting point
$$\mathbf{x}^0 = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{v}$$
With $\mathbf{x}$ the system solution. So the error is $\mathbf{e}^0 = \mathbf{v}$.
Thus:
$$
G\mathbf{e}^0 = \lambda \mathbf{e}^0 
\Rightarrow 
\mathbf{e}^k = G^k \mathbf{e}^0 = \lambda^k\mathbf{e}^0
$$

From the norm properties, 
$||\mathbf{e}^k|| = \lambda^k \cdot ||\mathbf{e}^0||$,
but by hypothesis $|\lambda| \geq 1$, so $\mathbf{e}^k$ cannot converge to zero. So if $\mathbf{x}^k \longrightarrow \mathbf{x}$ is necessary that $\rho(G) < 1$.

---

Note that the convergence is global and doesn't depend on the initial $\mathbf{x}^0$.

Comment: Note that it is possible for the method to converge because you "ingeniously" chose an initial vector which has no component in the direction of the "bad" eigenvector(s).

Comment: @Ian you are right. Lets me observe two computational and practical aspect. 1) Find a smart starting point it is not always easy (the info about eigenvector(s) often are not available or too heavy to obtain)  2) working with finite precision can happen that the component in bad direction is corrupt during the iterations, and this bad component can increase.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, then
$G = \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1 \\ 1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$, and the spectral radius is $1$.

Starting with $x_0 = e_1$, we get the sequence $e_1, e_2, e_1, e_2,...$ which
never converges.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.In this case It seems it sticks in a loop and never converges. In you example I understood what happens but I cannot see how can I use this for a larger matrix(that is not quite clear what initial guess will help avoid such loop).

Comment: Well, the example extends to any dimension $\ge 2$ is a straightforward manner. In the above case, $G^2$ has an eigenvalue of $-1$ hence it cannot converge if the initial condition has a component along a corresponding eigenvector.

Comment: I am trying to do more examples based on the point you made. Just another question if you don't mind : If the spectral radius is 1 and I have started with initial guess [0,...0] and it is converging so slow  Can I think changing initial guess will help to converge faster?

Comment: Because now I am guessing the problem is very slow convergence rate rather than sticking a loop.

Comment: If the spectral radius is one, then you can't, in general, guarantee convergence from any initial condition. Assuming that you are solving $Ax=b$, the answer to your question depends on the specific $A,b$. Maybe if you explain what you are trying to do, but generally if the radius is $1$ then you can't expect convergence.

Comment: One can write out an explicit formula for the $k$th iteration value and from this you can figure out some initial condition sort of thing.

Comment: I am trying to solve this for a large matrix(n=10000) and I know it should not takes more than a constant order of n to converge but is was taking forever. I look at the post below and I thought maybe if I change my initial guess it will help. I also find some paper talking about unit spectral radius but they are higher level.I cannot find a simple clue in textbook. Thanks for your help . I will try to work on it more. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665070/iterative-methods-what-happens-when-the-spectral-radius-of-a-matrix-is-exactly

Answer (score 0):

If the error/residual vector has components in the eigenspaces of the eigenvalues of absolute value $1$, then those components will never vanish, they will oscillate.

If an eigenvalue of absolute value $1$ has multiplicity greater 1, then the corresponding components can even grow like $$\text{(multiplicity)}^{\text{(iteration number)}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually there are 6 eigenvalues with absolute value equal to 1. But does it means it never converges? beacuse I am seeing the error decreases but very slowly.

Comment: Yes, the components of the residual vector in eigenspaces with eigenvalue of absolute value smaller than 1, inhale-exhale, they decrease. The reduction factor will increase from smallest to largest eigenvalue, and in our case it will approach 1, i.e., the reduction slows down to a stand-still, before the residual vector reaches zero.