# subtle issues related to Jacobi method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

Have 2 subtle queries regarding further properties related to Jacobi method

1) Given $Ax=b$, where

$A := \begin{bmatrix}
       4 & 1 & 0 \\
       1 & 4 & 3 \\
       0 & 0 & 4
      \end{bmatrix} $

standard application of Jacobi method is straightforward to determine the convergence of given method for specific system of equations.

- Besides, the use of column/row sum criterion can be used so to determine eigenvalues of the iteration's matrix in Jacobi method.
- Apart from row/column sum criterion, are there other methods for determination of convergence of Jacobi method without calculating eigenvalues?

2.) To determine value of parameter $a\in \mathbb{R}^+$, for which Jacobi method is convergent for every starting vector $x_{0}$ for the system of equations $Ax=b$, where:

$A := \begin{bmatrix}
     3 & a & 0  \\
    -1 & 1 & 1  \\
     0 & 0 & 3
     \end{bmatrix} $
,  $ b:=\begin{bmatrix} 3+a\\ 1 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$

is it just sufficient to determine eigenvalues of iteration's matrix in Jacobi method or to apply row/column sum criterion?

-I am not sure about the importance of vector $b$ in determinig the convergence of Jacobi method for specific system of equations.

Thanks in advance for help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I suppose that with:

> the use of column/row sum criterion can be used so to determine eigenvalues of the iteration's matrix in Jacobi method.

you're referring to [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), so I suggest the convergent criteria based on strict diagonal dominance.

> **QUESTION 1** Apart from row/column sum criterion, are there other methods for determination of convergence of Jacobi method without calculating eigenvalues?

For the Jacobi method (also for the Guass-Seidel) there is the theorem:

> **Theorem** If the system matrix $A$ is [strict diagonal dominance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) then the method converge

(for example see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Convergence) )

Note that this is a sufficient condition, NOT mandatory, but this is a criteria that doesn't require calculating eigenvalues.

> **QUESTION 2** is it just sufficient to determine eigenvalues of iteration's matrix in Jacobi method or to apply row/column sum criterion?

The condition about the spectral radius of the iteration matrix is a sufficient and mandatory condition for the global convergence of Jacabi method. See my answer to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010835/iteration-matrix-and-convergence/2018763#2018763). So if you calculate the eigenvalues of the iteration matrix ad you find/impose that $|\lambda_{max}| < 1$, you are ok.

Comment: thank you very much for help!

Comment: Now everything is clear for me.