# If the spectral radius of the iteration matrix is $1$ can convergence be possible?

Tags: linear-algebra

Regarding classical iterative methods such as Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel, and SOR there is an important criteria for the convergence of these iterative method if the spectral radius of the iterative matrix is less than $1$ and thereby ensuring convergence. My question is there a case where the spectral radius is exactly one and a convergence occured?

Answer (score 0):

The convergence condition is a *necessary and sufficient* one. i.e. an iterative method, such as Jacobi or Gauss-Seidel will converge **iff** the spectral radius (max absolute value of eigenvalues) of its iterative matrix is **strictly** less than $1$. So the answer to your question is NO.

For the reference, see [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B978012394435100020X) and [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665070/301977).

Comment: You probably mean convergence in the sense the error between the true solution and an initial guess goes to zero for all initial guesses. However, it seems possible for the method to converge (in the sense of having limit), but to a wrong solution. Say if the iteration matrix is the identity (with the spectral radius one) or for unlucky initial choice such that the error becomes in the null-space of the iteration.